# how to make filebeat pick up project-specific configuration file

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have the following yml file, in a project directory not the global file beat configuration directory:

```
filebeat:
  idle_timeout: 5s
  prospectors:
    paths:
      - "data-log/*"

output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

Running `filebeat -configtest` produces no output.
Running `filebeat` produces no output either.

I would like the running filebeat daemon to dynamically pick up the configuration from this directory, assuming that the command `filebeat` should do that. I know this can be set up in the global config file, but I would rather perfrom this dynamically.

What am I doing wrong or what assumptions implied here are false?

Comment: How about using the `-c /path/to/project/filebeat.yml` [command-line option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-command-line.html)?

Comment: I think that additional parameter should be meaningless, as it is already the default location when running `filebeat` with the project directory as the working directory.

Comment: You should try and see...

Comment: I know for a fact this is where configuration is taken from, as when the file is absent an error message ensues saying that the config file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

try to strace filebeat process with
`strace -fp {pid} -s 1024`, the lines you should be looking for are `stat({file_name}`.
This way you will see if filebeat resolves path correctly.